# ajax json_encode return sometimes takes too much time

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I'm developing an application in PHP with many ajax call.
Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'urltocall.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function(res) {...}
    error: function(data, errorThrown) {...}
});
```

on the other side in urltocall.php I have simple query to mysql and return the result with the command:

```
echo json_encode($results,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

Everything is very simple and fast. But I noticed some delays when values returns. So I tested all the parts of this process with microtime(), before and after ajax call, before and after query, before and after the json_encode command and the result is that this last command is the bottleneck of all ajax calls.
Changed web server, changed mysql server but sometimes I always have these delayes. 
Queries takes a few milliseconds, but json_encode "sometimes" takes 4 or 5 seconds to execute.
Tested on server with only my web server, mysql db with one account working on it with small tables and simple insert. Tried even php-fpm but always sometimes I have these delays.
I don't know where to look for a solution.

Comment: Weird. How many rows are we talking?

Comment: one insert, or one update, returns from 1 to 10 rows...

Comment: Pfft, beats me I'm afraid... could be a dodgy PHP install. Never heard of that.